# How can you add a button to the header of a TabPage?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, tabpage

Similar to how browsers close tabs, I was wondering if you can add a button to the header of a TabPage.

Would it use a custom TabPage renderer

Would I be able to add a button on the tab itself

Comment: Are you referring to tabitem inside tab control for winforms?

Comment: Yes, I want to add a close button to each individual tab that is created in the tabcontrol

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12323/A-TabControl-with-tab-page-closing-capability  OR http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/implementing-close-button-in-tab-pages/ OR http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20050/FireFox-like-Tab-Control

Comment: How about adding an image to the tabitem and working with the click event?

Comment: Yes that works. An image would be fine. Thank you YOusFzai for the links

Comment: @YOusaFZai, add your comment as an answer so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can find sample implementations here:

1. [A TabControl with tab page closing capability](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12323/A-TabControl-with-tab-page-closing-capability)
2. [Implementing Close button in Tab Pages](http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/implementing-close-button-in-tab-pages/)
3. [FireFox-like Tab Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20050/FireFox-like-Tab-Control)

Basically, you will write code that draws the button in the appropriate place (e.g. by overriding the `OnDrawItem` function), and then write some more code that handles clicks of this button.